# Не работает кнопка run в jetbrains rider

Tags: c#, jetbrains, rider

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я только начинаю изучать C#, и хотел бы поработать на этой среде разработки. Но я не могу запустить программу и не понимаю в что да как. Помогите пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит `не работает`?

Comment: @tym32167 Посмотрите пж на скриншот , не могу запустить программу, должно было выйти в консоли "hello world", а когда хотел запустить , run даже не видит его

Comment: Смотрю на скрин, не понимаю проблемы. У вас прямо в коде на строке 7, напротив метода Main есть зеленая стрелочка для запуска - пробовали нажать?

Comment: @tym32167 теперь посмотрите пж на 2 скрин, в первом я могу запустить, по не именно эту программу, а consoleApplication2. А когда создаю новый класс и там тоже самое то нет запуска программы

Comment: Вы пишете о чем то, что я не понимаю. Вам надо было запустить consoleApplication2? Вот вы его на своем скрине запустили и получили `hello world` в консоли. В новом классе вы метод `Main` зачем то с маленткой буквы назвали, попробуйте его скопировать с приложения, которое работает, чтобы не ошибаться.

Comment: и вы в курсе, что в приложении должен быть один метод Main? Если, конечно, вы не хотите плясать с параметрами компилятора.

Comment: нет нужно запустить только класс. И в 3 скринне ошибка выходит

Comment: @tym32167 на последнем скрине я работал с intellij idea, там несколько классов с различными работами с консолью. Я бы хотел точно так же в rider, несколько классов для работы с консолью , и запускать класс отдельно и знать какой класс запущен.

Comment: 1) Вам ошибка написана на скрине - нельзя называть классы и методы одним именем

Comment: 2) Вы не можете запустить класс, вы запускаете все приложение, только с разными точками входа

Comment: 3) Я не знаю, поддепживает ли Rider указание конкретной точки входа, но это на самом деле так себе практика. По крайней мере в C#

Comment: Я автору посоветую в Visual Studio поработать в C#, она бесплатна, больше возможностей и родней как то.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Спасибо, но я бы хотел именно на этой среде разработки

Comment: @tym32167 как тогда мне запустить новый класс ?

Comment: `2) Вы не можете запустить класс, вы запускаете все приложение, только с разными точками входа`

Comment: @tym32167 извиняюсь, как мне запустить с другого точки входа ?

Comment: `1) Вам ошибка написана на скрине - нельзя называть классы и методы одним именем` Вы класс Main переименовали? У вас сейчас какие проблемы с запуском?

Comment: @tym32167 да, но я не знаю как указать другую точку входа

Comment: `У вас прямо в коде на строке 7, напротив метода Main есть зеленая стрелочка для запуска - пробовали нажать?`

Comment: @tym32167 последнем скрине показано

Comment: `и вы в курсе, что в приложении должен быть один метод Main? Если, конечно, вы не хотите плясать с параметрами компилятора` - вот [параметр компилятора](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/main-compiler-option) - вы сами себе содаете трудности, указывая несколько Main методов. Я хз можно ли в Rider указать параметр компилятора (скорее всего можно где нибудь в файле проекта или солюшена), но это уже без меня, мне на такое жалко время тратить :)

Comment: @tym32167 а как без запускать? другие классы я не знаю, я только изучаю C#, и до этого в idea было легче. Если вы знаете как запустить другим способом  или найти другой выход, я только рад буду узнать

Comment: 1) Оставить только одну функцию Main 2) Внутри этой функции запускать нужный вам код

Comment: @tym32167 кстати, я не знал что я работал в приложении. И не знал что нельзя указывать в одном приложении несколько маинов не бывает

Comment: @tym32167 а с новым классом что? как вызвать метод main ?

Comment: ну сделайте `MyClass` со статической функцией `Run()` и вызывайте свой класс из функции `Main() { MyClass.Run(); }`

Comment: @tym32167 , можно ли на примере пожалуйста , я не знаю как это сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте обойтись одной функцией Main

```
public class MyEntryPoint
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyTestClas.Run();
    }
}

public class MyTestClas
{
    public static void Run()
    {
         // Ваш код тут
    }
}
```

Comment: Придется в первом классе каждый раз создавать объект на другие классы?

Comment: да (13 символов)

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь я получил ответ. Извиняюсь за доставленные не удобства

Comment: Пожалуйста. Хорошо, что разобрались.